# How can I call a function only after all properties have been set in my UIView subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a UIView subclass somewhat like this:

```
class AView: UIView {
    var aString = "A String"
    var aBool = true

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        func doSomethingWithTheString() {
            if aBool {
                doSomething(withString: aString)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I add a UIView to a storyboard and set it's class as `AView`. I link it to my view controller and do this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var aView: AView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    aView.aBool = false
    aView.aString = "Another String"
}
```

The thing is, when `doSomethingWithTheString()` is called `aBool` is still `true` and aString is still `"A String"`, even though I changed them at `viewDidLoad()`.

So is there somewhere in `AView` where I can put `doSomethingWithTheString()` for it to be called only when all properties have been set? I hoped `didMoveToSuperview()` would do the trick, but apparently it's still too early.

I thought of calling it in a property's setter, but I don't know which properties will be set and which will be left with their default, and it should only be called when the last property has been set.

Comment: Why not call it at the end of viewDidLoad?

Comment: @Eiko You mean call `aView.doSomethingWithTheString()`? Well, I might have to call a lot of functions and I don't want whoever uses my code to always have to call all those functions if they could be called automatically from `AView` itself. Also some functions might take in private properties as parameters or just parameters the user knows nothing about. So ideally I want to call it inside the `AView` class.

Comment: Weird definition of your functions: what is the behavior of `func didMoveToSuperview() {
        func doSomethingWithTheString() {}}`

Comment: @Xvolks Well, that was just an example. The view is actually a calendar and you can change it's first weekday. So the calendar's subviews should only be laid out after you've already set the first weekday.

Comment: Somehow the logic doesn't make sense. There is a proper way to initialize the object (i.e. init method), then there are methods that get called on special events like when the view did load, or when the view hierarchy changed. I guess you first need to think thoroughly about what you are trying to do and when and why.

Comment: It seems that all view management calls are done before `viewDidLoad` (after all `viewDidLoad` is meaningful). Maybe you can try modifying your properties in the `init(coder:)` initializer of the viewController?

Comment: @Eiko Yeah, but a custom `init()` is useless when adding the view in a storyboard.

Comment: Every object gets instantiated at some time, even those loaded from storyboards. ;)

Comment: @Eiko Of course, storyboard ones are instantiated with `init(coder)`, but I can't pass in other parameters, there's nowhere to do it from. Except perhaps runtime arguments, but they're pretty limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put aString and aBool in a dictionary (aDictionary) then declare

```
var aDictionary: NSDictionary? {
    didSet{
        doSomethingWithTheString()
    }
}
```

Of course change a bit the doSomethingWithTheString() to work with the dictionary

Comment: Creative solution. :) Thanks!